# Numbers look different in Safari on iPhone

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I have a simple snippet with a phone number composed by a one letter and 12 numbers, its a simple text inside a p element, In a desktop browser all looks fine, but in an iPhone browser the letter `p` looks fine but the rest of the number looks very small and there is a linebreak.

[image]

```css
 p.style3 {
  font-size: 3rem !important;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: lighter;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<p class="style3">p. 706.467.3000</p>
```

Why does Safari on iOS show this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (http://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/ZGBEvR):

**HTML:**

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<p class="style3">p. 706.467.3000</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p.style3 {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    font-size: 3rem !important;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: lighter;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**P.S.** `<meta>` should lie in `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change font size according mobile screen here is code

this should work

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px) { 
p.style3 {
  font-size: 3rem !important;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: lighter;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
}
```

Comment: It is meaningless write media query if you not change any of properties to the class, addictionally, my code it's inside a media queries now. but thanks

Comment: Try to write `font-size` in `px` not in `rem`